# Wrap Sub as Function for use in Lambda

Tags: vb.net, lambda, moq

I have a problem with VB9 and Moq.

I need to call a verify on a Sub. Like so:

```
logger.Verify(Function(x) x.Log, Times.AtLeastOnce)
```

And my logger looks like this:

```
Public Interface ILogger
    Sub Log()
End Interface
```

But with VB this is not possible, because the Log method is a Sub, and thereby does not produce a value.

I don't want to change the method to be a function.

Whats the cleanest way of working around this limitation and is there any way to wrap the Sub as a Function like the below?

```
logger.Verify(Function(x) ToFunc(AddressOf x.Log), Times.AtLeastOnce)
```

I have tried this, but i get:

> Lambda Parameter not in scope

Answer (score 1):

VB10 allows for the usage of Lambada Subs.

Have you tried a simple wrapper, such as:

```
Public Function Wrapper(source as Action) as Boolean  
    source.Invoke()   
    Return True 
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

In 2010 if its a Sub and not a Function just replace Function with Sub.

logger.Verify(**Sub**(x) x.Log, Times.AtLeastOnce)

Comment: i know this technically doesn't answer the question but I was using 2010 and stumbled upon this, so after i found the answer i came back to post it