# Func(Of Tin, Tout) using a lambda expression with ByRef argument gives incompatible signature error

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda, func, byref

Why does this:

```
Private [Function] As Func(Of Double, String) = Function(ByRef z As Double) z.ToString
```

gives the following error:

> Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate  String)'.

While this:

```
Private [Function] As Func(Of Double, String) = Function(ByVal z As Double) z.ToString
```

Does not?  (The difference is ByRef/ByVal)

Furthermore, how might I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting this error because the delegate type **Function (ByVal z As Double) As String** is not compatible with **Function (ByRef z As Double) As String**. You need exact match.

Also you can't declare the *Func(Of ...)* generic delegate with ByRef parameters (*ref* or *out* in C#), no matter are you using anonymous function or not.

But you can declare you delegate type and then use it even with your anonymous function

```
Delegate Function ToStringDelegate(ByRef value As Double) As String

Sub Main()
    Dim Del As ToStringDelegate = Function(ByRef value As Double) value.ToString()
End Sub
```

or you can use implicit typing (if the Option Infer is turned on)

```
Dim Del = Function(ByRef value As Double) value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 6):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) it mentions the following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:

- A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it goes out of scope.
- Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in the outer method.
- **A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref [ByRef in VB] or out parameter from an enclosing method.**
- A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the enclosing method to return.
- A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement, or continue statement whose target is outside the body or in the body of a contained anonymous function.